# Using gcc/clang builtins on windows

Tags: windows, gcc, clang, built-in

I'm trying to compile a c++ project on Windows. This project works perfectly on OSX/Linux.

It uses a fair number of gcc builtins. popcount, builtin_expect etc.

I know that MS-Visual-Studio has a clang compiler you can install! And I have it installed. So... how do I get my project to compile on windows using clang?

Right now I'm trying to go through each compile-error and fix them to work on Windows. Which is time-consuming.

I'm doing it with ifdefs:

```
#ifdef TARGET_WINDOWS
    #define __typeof__ decltype
    #define __hot inline
    #define __builtin_popcount __popcnt
#else
    #define __hot inline __attribute__((always_inline))
#endif
```

It would make my life A LOT easier if I had ONE code-base to compile from, rather than have to re-write (port) every gcc builtin to a Windows equivalent.

Do I manually port every built-in (or just missing names/alternate names) over to windows using #ifdefs, or can I use gcc builtins on Windows via clang?

I tried using the clang compiler on windows (via msvc's "toolset" project-property), but it doesn't seem to know anything about all the gcc builtins :(

No idea what to do.

Comment: There is also mingw if clang doesn't work for you.

Comment: I was hoping to compile this using cmake. And do it using a typical visual-studio setup. Just wondering if it's possible.